# GAE - Should I chain asynchronous callbacks?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, asynchronous, rpc

I'm new to using asynchronous callbacks and I'm not sure if what I'm planning out is the appropriate way to go about doing things. I'm working with Google App Engine along with Google Web Toolkit, and they provide a simple way to perform asynchronous callback methods with their RPC service. I've got the basic asynchronous callbacks working fine, but now I'm looking to do something a little more complicated. I want to set things up so that the part of my web app that's immediately available to the user will be loaded first so that there's something for the user to use as quick as possible. Then the next most available parts will be loaded and so on. Eventually I might even want to get more complicated and load everything in the order I just described unless the user clicks to do something else, then load that part first.

The way I'm thinking about doing this is just using the asynchronous function calls in GAE and GWT and just on a success of the one call start the next one. This should work, but the more parts that need to be loaded the more this code becomes a bit like spaghetti. Is there a better way to make and organize these asynchronous calls? Does Google provide a better method to organize this that I don't know about? Also, am I going down a completely wrong road and should be doing something very different? Thank you much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, rpc calls are not the way to load parts of your site.

see this instead ... https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting

Per their example, suppose you wanted to split out the Window.alert call into a separate code download:

> Button b = new Button("Click me", new ClickHandler() {
>
> ```
>   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
>     GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
>       public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
>         Window.alert("Code download failed");
>       }
>
>       public void onSuccess() {
>         Window.alert("Hello, AJAX");
>       }
>     });
>   }
> });
> ```